# Not getting proper output while running 'detection' demo of ChainerCV

Tags: chainer, chainercv

I am trying to run a 'detection' demo of ChainerCV from here,
https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/tree/master/examples/detection

I am running this demo in **BitFusion Ubuntu 14.04 Chainer AMI** on AWS with a p2.xlarge instance which uses a single GPU.

When I try to run this demo at first I am getting this error,

> no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

So I researched it on the web and get a solution for using matplotlib with AGG engine, so I tried to import that and use agg.
That does solve the problem of $DISPLAY but now when I run the demo it gets executed successfully but as an output, all I get is a white blank image.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you run the demo program in remote machine and X is not properly set.
You can get proper matplotlib output when you connect to your remote machine with `ssh -X <your.remote.machine.address>`, but it will takes time to show the resultt.

If you want to run demo in remote machine quickly, i recommend you to set `MPLBACKEND=Agg`, save plot figure as image by `plt.savefig(<imagepath>)` and do not run `plt.show()` in demo program.